# A set of rules that defined requisites for two individuals becoming close. I can't seem to remember the rules of the theorem

Tags: social-psychology

A long time ago (early in my undergrad), in one of my Psychology courses, I was exposed to this list (not sure if it was some established, well known theory or just some list that my textbook had come up with) that listed things that brought two people closer together. The only thing I remember on the list was "time spent together", in that the more time two individuals spend with each other, in particular alone, the closer they become.

Does this ring a bell to anyone? Do you know any sort of lists (from a source, possibly your own head) that are similar to this? I'm really just curious, it was something I thought about a lot when I was younger and want to revisit it for fun.

Comment: This [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I9hJ_Rux9y0&t=701s) has a list with "time spent together" being first.  Also related: [How to test people's compatibility for friendship](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/21084/7001).